# SQL server update error - Msg 2627

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

I am trying to update my table "tender".

It has these columns:

- requisition no(rq_no)
- requisition year(rq_year)
- tender number(te_no)
- te_date
- te-due_date
- tender status(te_status)
- te_year

I tried the below code:

```
update tender 
set te_status='D'
where rq_no like 'Q052401C' AND te_year like '2012' and te_no like 'n0066'
```

if I place any other character in place of `'D'` in `te_status`, update is successful except for 'D'
e.g.:

```
set te_status='S'
```

When I run

```
SELECT * FROM TENDER
WHERE
    rq_no LIKE 'Q052401C' AND te_year LIKE '2012' AND te_no LIKE 'n0066'
```

, it returns a single row.

Ιt shows me the following error:

> Msg 2627, Level 14, State 1, Line 1
>   Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_tender'.
>   Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.tender'.
>   The duplicate value is (N0066, Q052401C, D, 2012)
>   The statement has been terminated.

What does all these mean?

Answer (score 2):

It means you have a primary key defined on that table, which consists of the fields relating to the values it displayed - i.e. (N0066, Q052401C, D, 2012) - and that if you change the te-status field to D on the row you are updating, then this results in a primary key that already exists.

Depending on the DB you use, you sometimes can't UPDATE a primary key field - you should do a DELETE of the old row and an INSERT of the changed row (with the new key).